# building android_core failed

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build rosjava_core and android_core from source with Android SDK (r17) and ROS (electric). Here are the steps I've tried:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava rosjava_core
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.android android_core
```

From http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html

```
roscd rosjava_core
./gradlew install
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/__init__.py", line 80, in get_lexer_by_name
    raise ClassNotFound('no lexer for alias %r found' % _alias)
ClassNotFound: no lexer for alias u'groovy' found
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-xdEEl7.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
Either send bugs to the mailing list at <http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/>,
or report them in the tracker at <http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issues/>. Thanks!
make: *** [html] Error 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':docs:install'.
> Command 'make' finished with (non-zero) exit value 2.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  
BUILD FAILED
```

I've tried with: `./gradlew install -x docs:install`

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 mins 13.005 secs
```

From http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html

```
roscd android_core
./gradlew debug
```

BUILD FAILED

```
/home/hado/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:651: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/hado/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:672: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_honeycomb_mr2:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Could you please give me idea how to fix those failures. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31474/building-android_core-failed/) by [hado](https://answers.ros.org/users/2147/hado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-11**:
As suggested, please post the output from running with --info/--debug/--stacktrace since the cause of the build failure is not in the output you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're missing the compressed_visualization_transport_msgs package. If you install the google stack (http://ros.org/wiki/google, ./gradlew install) this error should go away. You may need to try ./gradlew clean debug.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1